# Python persisting function result in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently refactoring code to use different input data sources, to do so I am using a proxy module which calls different data sources to get (lets say prices, returns for equities) details.

I am writing data getters in the modules that are going to be called by the proxy class. I am expected to have several such modules working. Lets say this module contains 3 functions to get 3 fields say A,B and C. The modules will return a dict object to the proxy file which in turn returns the dict to the main file.

The main file will call the proxy file for A then do some computations then call proxy for B and then some more computations then calls proxy for C. Since A,B,C will go to the same data source (there are multiple sources but we stay consistent with getting data in the sense that if you are using Bloomberg for A you use Bloomberg for B and C as well or if you use Reuters for A you use Reuters for B and C also)

I want to be able to do the create the A,B and C dictionaries when the request for A comes to the module. What I have a problem with is that although I can create A,B and C, I dont know how store the B and C dicts in the proxy class or in the appropriate module after calculating it as a dict object or something so that when the request for B comes I do not have to send a request to the module again.

I do not have to do this, there is no difference in terms of efficiency or space complexity, but I was wondering how I would do this.

So far I have seen storing data into a file using json/pickling and then reading it but I want a better solution without file I/O.

mainfile.py:

```
import proxy as P
A_data = P.getdata(A)
...
B_data = P.getdata(B)
...
C_data = P.getdata(C)
```

proxy.py:

```
import data_source.bberg as B
import data_source.reut as R

def getdata(data_type):
  #defaulting to B just for demonstration, data_type is A or B or C
  if data_type == A:
     return B.getA()
  if data_type == B:
     return B.getB()
  if data_type == C:
     return B.getC()
```

bberg.py:

```
def getA():
     details = {}
     ... # fill it with details
     return details
  # similar implementations for getB() and getC(), return a dict object
```

I want to make it so that 
the code behaves like this

```
    A_global = {}
    B_global = {}
    C_global = {}
    if data_type == A:
       A_global =  B.getA()
       B_global = B.getB()
       C_global = B.getC()
   # A,B and C are populated now and when `getdata(B)` is called it should just return `B_global` and not go to bberg.py
```

This way could be completely wrong but I was wondering if i can make `A_global`, `B__global` persist between calls to `getdata(datatype)`

structure:

```
app/
 mainfile.py
 proxy.py

 data_source/ 

  bberg.py
  reut.py
```

Comment: This is super abstract and very hard to follow in terms of what you want to do.  Can you please post an MCVE of what you are doing currently so that we can offer assistance?

Comment: yes , on it. will try to make a diagram

Comment: Can you also please provide some sample code as to what you're doing? Just a block of text is really difficult to follow.

Comment: @2ps updated my q

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp does the update help?